# Redirecting after inserting query execution not working

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I have been trying to redirect after inserting into the database but it's not working. The insert is working perfectly but it's not redirecting here is my code

```
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    
    $query = "INSERT INTO investment (userid, amount, status, hashID, plan) 
              VALUES('$uidb', '$amount', '$status', '$id', '$plan')";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      exit(header('location: https://google.com'));
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Invalid Sort Code");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you have any output before that code?

Comment: Also, that if condition will always fail as it will be `0`.  Try https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: no there is no output before the code sir

Comment: `exit(header('location: https://google.com'));` - why ?!? Please separate this to `header('Location: ...'); exit;`

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Why would you recommend that. It's simpler to do it in one go. Your suggestion is not an improvement at all.

Comment: For `INSERT` queries, use `mysqli_affected_rows`, not `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: thanks alot guys for all your effort all leads to it working i really appreciate

Comment: @Dharman please any directions on where to get these materials i really dont know much am just doing the little i can thanks for your advice please any link on where to get to understand these (PDO & Mysqli)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @AbraCadaver and @Lars Stegelitz commented try this:

but even BETTER DO THIS with prepared statements for a bettter security.

if (count($errors) == 0) {

```
$query = "INSERT INTO investment (userid, amount, status, hashID, plan) 
          VALUES('$uidb', '$amount', '$status', '$id', '$plan')";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_affected_rows($db)) == 1) {
  header('location: https://google.com');
}else {
    array_push($errors, "Invalid Sort Code");
}
```

}

Comment: thanks alot this worked it God bless you